Add button missing in Facebook Page Roles
I’ve worked for weeks trying to add another person in Page Roles (whose name is missing as well) to my Facebook business account.
It only has the one person that is assigned a roll currently; it has three dots to the right, and when clicked, it simply says “remove.” Under community, it has that person and has no “add button” at all, anywhere.
This has messed up everything on my Facebook business page.

Welcome to Web Apps SE! It will be helpful if you [edit] your post and provide a screenshot or two of the issue. Also, please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
